# Comma separated on single line in HAML

Tags: haml

Using HAML, I'd like to have links in a single line with commas in between. Like so,

`Check me out on GitHub, Twitter, Coderwall and LinkedIn.`

Here's what I've got:

```
%footer
  Check me out on
  %a{:href => url('http://github.com/bostonaholic')} Github
  ,
  %a{:href => url('http://www.twitter.com/bostonaholic')} Twitter
  ,
  %a{:href => url('http://coderwall.com/bostonaholic')} Coderwall
  and
  %a{:href => url('http://www.linkedin.com/in/mboston')} LinkedIn
  \.
```

But this comes out like this:

```
Check me out on GitHub , Twitter , Coderwall and LinkedIn .
```

How do I fix this so the commas and period are in the correct spots?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HAML has considered this case with the `succeed` helper. Docs here: http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#succeed-instance_method

This HAML

```
click
= succeed '.' do
  %a{:href=>"thing"} here
```

produces

```
click
<a href='thing'>here</a>.
```

Comment: Thank you @josal. I think this should be the accepted method.

Answer (score 5):

This is a huge and long-standing problem in HAML. I have solved this personally in two different ways.

**1) I put the text I want inside of array elements, and use a**

```
join(', ')
```

But this is a pretty shite way to do things.

**2) The HAML only "solution" lies in the special > character. The > character removes whitespace in the output html to so there is no whitespace BEFORE or AFTER this tag is output.**

This is the best I've been able to come up with, and I loose sleep at night over it's frightful ugliness.

```
  %a{:href => 'here'} Github
  %span> ,&nbsp;
  %a{:href => 'there'} Twitter
```

Notes on this last technique.

a. If you don't use the &nbsp ; you won't get a space, even if there is on in your source code.  Using quotes ( %span> #{", "}) and a space doesn't work, as apparently HAML trims the output.

b. You have to use a tag because using > only works after a tag as far as I can tell. Using => will unfortunately not work. This would be my recommended way to do it, but it would not solve the last space being lost anyway.

**3) In my rails projects I use the following combination of partials and helpers:**

partial: _haml_comma.html.haml

```
%span> ,&nbsp;
```

helper.rb

```
  def comma
    render :partial => "shared/haml_comma"
  end
```

.haml file:

```
  %a{:href => 'here'} Github
  = comma
  %a{:href => 'there'} Twitter
```

**4) When you have an ENUMERABLE and are LOOPING, the following helper and partial may help you**

**application_helper.rb**

```
  # puts a comma after an element in a loop EXCEPT the last loop
  def comma_separate(i:, total:, &block)
    render layout: 'shared/comma_separate', locals: {i:i, total: total} do
      capture(&block) if block
    end
  end
```

**views/shared/_comma_separate.html.haml :**

```
= succeed i + 1 < total ? ', ' : nil do
  %span.some_class<
    = yield
```

**in your view:**

```
- enumerable.each_with_index do |w, i|
  = comma_separate i: i, total: enumerable.size do
    %b
      = w
```

(This edit was made in 2019, a full 5 years after the first comment. Why isn't this solved HAML maintainers?)

Answer (score 2):

Using the haml 'succeed' helper (thanks @josal), here is a clean, simple way to do it:

```
%footer
  Check me out on
  = succeed ',' do
    %a{:href => url('http://github.com/bostonaholic')} Github
  = succeed ',' do
    %a{:href => url('http://www.twitter.com/bostonaholic')} Twitter
  = succeed 'and' do
    %a{:href => url('http://coderwall.com/bostonaholic')} Coderwall
  = succeed '.' do
    %a{:href => url('http://www.linkedin.com/in/mboston')} LinkedIn
```

I find about the only time I need this is when working with links, but it's a good tool to have in your haml belt.